# iPad app with variable speed video playback?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, video

I would like to watch recorded lectures at 1.7x of their original speed.

Which app will allow me to do that?

Comment: 1.7x their original speed? Must be a boring lecture, eh? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any playback app on the iPad with the exact 1.7 ratio...

However, [Azul for iPad (app store link)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/azul-media-player-your-password/id404452499?mt=8) has 1.5 and 1.75 playback ratios.  They even say in their site blurb that it's good for fast reviewing of lectures.

Reviews are excellent and integration with Mail and Dropbox is there, as well as a very comprehensive codec list

Answer (score 6):

I built [Swift Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swift-player-speed-up-video/id545216639?mt=8) for iPhone and iPad that will allow you to change (speed up) the playback speed of video and audio from the device or even directly from websites like YouTube, etc.

You can find out more information [on the product's website](http://www.tapparatus.com/swift).

**Note:** This is a product that I have developed.

Comment: Does this app just speed the audio/video?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Its main function is to adjust playback speed of audio or video files.  It has other bells and whistles like downloading for offline viewing, etc.  Check the site for all the features.

Comment: This is marketing. :( You are doing this to increase your sales. :(

Comment: Well, I did state it's a shameless plug, and it's not like i'm saying this out of context.  I built this app because I was lacking a solution for the very same reason this thread is about.  And the question the user asked was of an app that does this.  Every other answer is of an app, are you sure they aren't "marketing".

Comment: @dizy, I'm sorry, I left a word off ("up") in my comment - so I wasn't clear. I understand now.

Comment: @Robottinosino, Please view the [faq#promotion]. It is actually perfectly fine to post a relavent link to one's own work. And he disclosed that he built it, which is the only other requirement (on-topic, and disclosure).

Comment: awesome app, just downloaded.

Comment: I've been using this app for several years and I think it's the best out there.  It would be nice if it handled playlists better, though

Comment: I had this app and I loved it, but now I get "The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store."

Answer (score 1):

VLC will allow you to playback at any speed between 0.25x and 4x in increments of 0.01x.  Choose the clock icon from the lower toolbar during playback to see a slider.

VLC can be downloaded from http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html (links to Apple's [AppStore](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id650377962?pt=454758&ct=vodownloadpage&mt=8)

Comment: Unfortunately, the VLC Media player port for iOS is a bit basic. As of 2012-06-08 it does not support variable speed playback (pity, as it is a nice app in most other respects).

Answer (score 1):

[Speedeo](http://www.speedeoapp.com) just came out for both iPhone and iPad and allows you to increase / decrease videos in 0.25 increments. You can also resume watching videos quickly from the history screen. You can view videos from 0.25x to 2x speed, quite neat for watching presentations / tutorials.

Note: I am one of the developers of this app

Answer (score 1):

[PDF Expert](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pdf-expert-pdf-editor-reader/id743974925), despite the name, has a great video player with variable speed (0.5x, 0.8x, 1.0x, 1.25x, 1.5x, 1.75x, 2.0x) and also 2-finger swiping gestures for seeking and brightness, and double-tap forward/back gestures like the YouTube app. Many ways to import and manage videos/files.

I'm not affiliated; just love how much effort and polish they have put into this free app.

Answer (score 0):

[AVPlayerHD](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/avplayerhd/id407976815?mt=8) supports 1.05 to 2x in 0.05 increments (and is available in the Swedish Itunes Store, which Swift Player and Azul aren't, and I assume other non-US users will have the same problem.)

I am not affiliated with this app.

Comment: If you are the author of this app, please edit your answer to indicate this.

Answer (score -3):

As an author I could recommend a new Free iOS player with variable playback speed and many other adjustable playback options [alphaSXplayer](http://www.alphasxplayer.com/)

[image]

Comment: When promoting your software here, you should add in your post that you are affiliated, in this case you're the author of the software.  It's considered 'bad form' to provide your software as an answer **without indicating** it's your software.

Comment: I edited my comment and picked what it is a my software. I hope, it is better. Thank for your notice.